# Do all correlation coefficients induce a pseudometric?

Tags: co.combinatorics, st.statistics, simplicial-stuff

The Kendall tau distance was originally defined as a correlation coefficient. It seems clear to me that every metric function $d$ that is bounded by $b$, induces a correlation coefficient. That is:

Let $d$ be a metric. Then $-d(x,y)/b+1$ is a correlation coefficient.

I wonder if the converse is true, too:

Let $c(x,y)$ be a correlation coefficient. Then $-c(x,y) + 1$ is a pseudometric.

Is the latter statement true or false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is false. Consider the Pearson sample correlation coefficient:

c(x,y) = (x-mean(x)).(y-mean(y))/sqrt(|x-mean(x)|^2*|y-mean(y)|^2)

Here is an example, where the triangle inequality for the distance defined in 
the question is not satisfied

x = [0.5847   -0.3048   -0.4431    0.5032   -0.3401],

y = [0.2018    0.4547   -0.2230    0.3350   -0.7685],

z = [0.5226   -0.5159   -0.5439    0.3701    0.1671].